# how to replace last comma with "and"

Tags: c#

I want to replace *last comma* with `"and"` in my C# sample and full stop at the end.

I am trying the below code:

```
result = (result.LastIndexOf(",") == result.Length - 2) 
        ? result.Remove(result.LastIndexOf(","), 2) 
        : result;

result += ".";
```

Where my current output comes like this:

> abc, def, ghi.

Expected:

> > abc, def and ghi.

I need to replace the last coma with `and`. I tried using `replace` but it didn't work.

Comment: How did you get at the `== result.Length - 2` logic?

Comment: Best advice: forget about `?:` and write a proper `if() {}`

Comment: @liam - but only the last one.

Comment: @Liam did you realise that there are two commas and OP only wants to replace the _last_ one?

Comment: How did you build the result? Instead of fixing the already created string we could help to build the right string.

Comment: my result is parsed from a string which consists of many logs and i am extracting particular data from it

Comment: @Justin if one of the answers helped you, you could repay the favour and select one of them as accepted. If you don't know how to do it then [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) might help. Happy coding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```cs
var test = "Service Control Manager repeated 5 times, " +
    "Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM repeated 2 times, " +
    "Control Manager repeated 6 times.";
var lastComma = test.LastIndexOf(',');
if (lastComma != -1) test = test.Remove(lastComma, 1).Insert(lastComma, " and");
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is one (naive) way to do it:

```
result = result.Substring(0, result.LastIndexOf(',')) 
         + " and" 
         + result.Substring(result.LastIndexOf(',')+1);
```

It's naive because it assumes that there is at least one `,` in the string and it's not the last char in it.

So you want to put in inside a condition:

```
if(result.LastIndexOf(',') < result.Length-1)
{
    result = result.Substring(0, result.LastIndexOf(',')) 
             + " and" 
             + result.Substring(result.LastIndexOf(',')+1);
}
```

Noticed how this code repeats `LastIndexOf(',')` 3 times? This can be fixed by using a variable. Also, as Ian H wrote in his comment, we should verify that there is at least one `,` in the string, so here is the final version:

```
var lastComma = result.LastIndexOf(',');
if(lastComma > -1 && lastComma < result.Length - 1)
{
    result = result.Substring(0, lastComma) 
             + " and" 
             + result.Substring(lastComma + 1);
}
```

Comment: You could additionally check if the last index of the result is larger than `-1`, in case no comma is found.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why no one mentioned Regex, which seems the shortest option:

```
string source = "UK, USA, Canada, New Zealand";
string result = Regex.Replace(source, ", ([^,]+)$", " and $1");
Console.WriteLine($"result is {result}");
// UK, USA, Canada and New Zealand
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not `Substring`?

```
// Let's cache the position in order not to scan several times
int position = result.LastIndexOf(',');

if (position >= 0) // do we have anything to cut out?
  result = result.Substring(0, position).TrimEnd() +    // before 
           " and " +                                    // change , to and
           result.Substring(position + 1).TrimStart();  // after
```

I suggest using `TrimEnd()` as well as `TrimStart()` in order to obtain a well formatted text:

```
"a,   b" -> "a and b"
"a  , b" -> "a and b"
"a   ,b" -> "a and b"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string input = "Service Control Manager repeated 5 times, Microsoft-Windows-DistributedCOM repeated 2 times, Control Manager repeated 6 times.";

string [] allparts = input.Split(',');

string result = string.Join(",", allparts.Take(allparts.Count() -1)) + " and" + allparts.Last();

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: @Justin you are welcome, personally I would use the solution by Zohar Peled. It is much more straight forward and intuitive

Answer (score 1):

This might be overkill, but given that replacing a last occurrence of something is a common task, I thought of going the String/StringBuilder **extension method** route:

```
 public static class Extensions
{
    //extension method for StringBuilder (possible becuase StringBuilder has a more configurable Replace method than does String). 
    public static StringBuilder ReplaceLastOccurenceOf (this StringBuilder sb, string thingToReplace, string replacement)
        {
            return sb.Replace(thingToReplace, replacement, sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(thingToReplace), thingToReplace.Length);
        }

    // The extension method for string actually calls on the one for StringBuilder, converting it back to string at the end
    public static string ReplaceLastOccurenceOf (this string s, string thingToReplace, string replacement)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ; sb.Append(s); //create the SB instance and give it the string's val
            return sb.ReplaceLastOccurenceOf(thingToReplace, replacement).ToString(); 
        }
}
```

And call them thus:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string[] cities = { "London", "Delhi", "Paris", "New York"};

        //work with StringBuilder
        var sbCities = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string city in cities) { sbCities.Append(city + ", ");}
        sbCities.Remove(sbCities.Length-2, 2); // remove last comma and space

        Console.WriteLine($"sbCities = {sbCities}");
        Console.WriteLine("Cities  you've visited are " + sbCities.ReplaceLastOccurenceOf("Paris", "Karachi").ReplaceLastOccurenceOf(",", " and"));
        Console.WriteLine();

        //now for String
        string stringCities = string.Join(", ", cities);
        Console.WriteLine($"stringCities = {stringCities}");
        Console.WriteLine("Cities  you've visited are " + stringCities.ReplaceLastOccurenceOf("Paris", "Karachi").ReplaceLastOccurenceOf(",", " and"));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

}
```

[Fiddle Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rKsinE)